# C# Passing Table Valued Parameter to SqlCommand not Working

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to run a test case, and this won't even work...
What am I doing wrong here?

Here's the SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    Playground.Test (saved DateTime)
GO
CREATE TYPE
    Playground.DateTimeTable AS TABLE
    ([time] DATETIME);
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE
    Playground.InsertDate
    @dt Playground.DateTimeTable READONLY
AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Playground.Test (saved) 
        SELECT [time] 
        FROM @dt
    END
GO
```

And code to connect and execute the procedure:

```
const String connString = 
    "server = SERVER; database = DB; UID = myUserID; pwd = myPassword;";
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlCommand command =
        new SqlCommand(
            "EXEC Playground.InsertDate",
            new SqlConnection(connString));

    DataTable table = new DataTable("DateTimeTable");
    table.Columns.Add("[time]", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Rows.Add(DateTime.Parse("10/27/2004"));

    SqlParameter tvp = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", table);
    tvp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    tvp.TypeName = "Playground.DateTimeTable";

    command.Connection.Open();
    int affected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Connection.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(affected);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I'm not getting any errors. Just 0 rows affected.

This works in SQL Server, though:

```
DECLARE @dt Playground.DateTimeTable
INSERT INTO @dt VALUES ('2004-10-27')
EXEC Playground.InsertDate @dt
```

What am I supposed to be doing here?

Comment: Can you profile your server to see what SQL is being executed?

Comment: Though I would suggest removing `EXEC` from the command and setting `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Comment: @DavidG the other solution would be to make the command text `EXEC Playground.InsertDate @dt`. Thanks for the clue!

Comment: I prefer being explicit about my `SqlCommand` properties, but that might work too. Let me know...

Comment: @DavidG, yep. Declaring `CommandType.StoredProcedure` just means that it will get the definition before executing, and use the parameter names in the definition, meaning it essentially resolves the command text to `EXEC Playground.InsertDate @dt`. Adding parameters just makes them available to your command text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting your `SqlCommand` object to be a stored procedure. You should do a couple of things:

1. Remove the `EXEC` prefix from the string ~(it's not needed)
2. Set `command` to be a stored procedure:

   ```
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   ```
3. Not sure how the square braces around the `DataTable` column names will affect this either, but I suspect it's better with them removed.

Comment: Square braces are just there from autogenerated code, it just helps to prevent escaping issues like names starting with numbers, spaces in the name, or a name that is the same as a reserved word like "FROM". The square bracket forces "Everything between the start and the end of these brackets is the object name". It is easier for the auto generated code to have them there all the time instead of detecting when they are needed and only adding them then.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I know that (at least in SQL Server), I'm just not sure they are needed in the context of the `DataTable` column name.

Comment: AHH, you where talking about `table.Columns.Add("[time]", typeof(DateTime));`, I did not see that. I thought you where talking about the `([time] DATETIME);`