# How to use a stored procedure to add a row of data to one table and multiple rows of data to another table- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm very new to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and really need some help on a problem.

I am working on a database for a gym. They want to add/'register' a new member via a stored procedure. I have this figured out thankfully as it only requires adding 1 row of data on a table.

They also want to add the member's custom workout details. I have managed to write a separate stored procedure for this.

**However** they want to be able to add the member's custom workout at the same time.

This requires adding multiple rows of data to a 'Workout' table for that specific member and adding 1 row to the 'Member' table.

For example:

**Member** table might look like this:

```
MemberID    MemberName 
----------------------
   01       John
```

**Workout** table might look like this:

```
MemberID   Exercise  
------------------
  01       Deadlift  
  01       Burpee  
  01       Squat
```

I ideally want the user to exec a stored procedure and insert the below data to populate both the `Member` and `Workout` table

```
exec ADD_MEMBER 02, Mary, Deadlift, Squat, Jogging
```

The result would be

**Member** table:

```
MemberID   MemberName
-------------------
  01       John
  02       Mary
```

**Workout** table

```
MemberID   Exercise  
-----------------
  01       Deadlift
  01       Burpee
  01       Squat
  02       Deadlift
  02       Squat
  02       Jogging
```

Any advice on how to allow the user to do this?

Comment: You ought to look at [table-valued parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) (TVPs). You ought to banish the thought of using a comma-delimited string with multiple values jumbled together.

Comment: @HABO yes I do actually have a TVP for populating the Workout table. So now I'm thinking how to create a stored procedure that will allow the user to populate the TVP stored protocol and a single row addition stored protocol at the same time. EG EXEC ProtocolName (MemberID, MemberName, Exercise1, Exercise2, Exercise3) where the MemberID and MemberName go into the Member table as 1 row and then Exercises 1-3 go into the Workout table as 3 separate rows.

Comment: Most end users, e.g. gymnasts, don't use SSMS to access the database. If you were writing an application in C# with .NET then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600117/c-sharp-passing-table-valued-parameter-to-sqlcommand-not-working) question and answer demonstrate how to pass a table from C# to a stored procedure. Aside: Somewhere along the line you'll want [`Scope_Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. With a rather exhaustive answer, I'm afraid. I'll try to be as short as possible.

For a start, I think you need to consider the fact, that the customer is responsible for specifying functional requirements and quality aspects, and you (as a developer/designer) are responsible for the fancy, geeky, technical implementations.

I assume that the end user will not be using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) for calling the stored procedures... right? I assume you will create some kind of application with a nice and flashy user interface, which will execute any SQL queries and/or stored procedures based on the data that is entered by the user... right?

So how you actually implement the storage logic is practically entirely up to you. As I see it, it's just fine to create and call separate stored procedures or execute single queries. But it is important that the application will wait with executing those queries and/or stored procedures until the user is ready with entering all the data about the new member.

I guess it's the idea, that the user can enter and keep all the data in the application's user interface (forms or webpages) until eventually a Save-button is pressed. When that Save-button is pressed, all the required SQL queries and/or stored procedures should be executed (in the right order, of course) to store everything correctly in the database. You probably also want to execute everything within a database transaction, so that in the end of the save routine either everything succeeds or everything fails. (That's what I would actually think what a customer would mean by saying "at the same time".)

Of course, it's technically possible to put everything inside a single stored procedure, but that implementation would become pretty complex quite quickly, I'm afraid. (It would likely involve some stored procedure parameters containing structured data, like table parameters or XML parameters, since SQL Server does not have any native array data types.) So with respect to flexibility, scalability and maintainability aspects of your application, I would strongly advise against that strategy, especially if you are relatively new to developing these kind of database applications.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Bart